# How to copy old files in old partition to primary partition?

Tags: file-management, permissions

I recently switched from Windows 7 to elementary OS. I copied my important files from my Local Disk C to Local Disk D. I installed elementary OS in Local Disk C. After that I wanted to restore my Local Disk D files to Local Disk C in the root of my elementary partition but whenever I try to copy, it says that:

> The folder "" cannot be copied because you do not have permissions to create it in the destination.

I'm new to Linux.

`lsblk` result:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 236.7G  0 part /
├─sda3   8:3    0 221.6G  0 part /media/trebz/36902D4A902D11C3
├─sda4   8:4    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0   7.5G  0 part [SWAP]
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

I'm going to copy it to sda1 from sda3. So I successfully copied it to my home directory but I want it in my file system drive.

Comment: Please add the output of `lsblk`. Where did you want to copy the files to? Did you try copying to your home directory?

Comment: What command(s) are you using?  What (if anything) are you doing to access "Local Disk D" from Linux?

Comment: @G-Man He switched from windows and is new to linux. I'm very sure he did drag and drop the files with the default file manager.

Comment: @G-Man yes i just drag and drop. As what i have said i'm new to linux.

Comment: @michas so what should I do?

Comment: @treblaluch Find out, how to open a terminal. Open terminal. Enter "lsblk". Copy output. Edit your question and add output. Think about you trying to copy the files. What was the location you tried to copy the files to? Add a sentence containing the answer to your question. Locate your home directory (or even simpler your desktop). Try to copy the files to there. Add another sentence to your question describing the result. Find some [manual](https://elementary.io/docs/learning-the-basics) for your new OS.

Comment: @michas see post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32833/discussion-between-michas-and-treblaluch).

Answer (score 1):

On elementary OS, and every other linux, and every other Unix. Files are organized in a special directory structure.

Type `man hier` or ask [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) or look at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138547/how-to-understand-the-ubuntu-file-system-layout) to learn about this.

On windows you would not try to put your files under `C:\windows\`. The same way you would not put your files under `/`(the root directory) on linux.

On linux it is your home directory where your files live and where you have the right to do pretty much anything. Most of the other directories are system directories and you do not have permissions to write there.

Comment: but what if im trying to move like for example my dota 2 files to the new installed steam in linux would it possible? Cause re-downloading it takes a lot of time.